# What do these lines in the Google+ robots.txt mean?

Tags: robots.txt

http://plus.google.com/robots.txt has the following contents:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /_/
```

I'm assuming this means search engines are allowed to index anything in the first level off the root and nothing further?

Comment: the _ is non-standard as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe those lines are used to deny robots access to URLs like
[`https://plus.google.com/_/apps-static/_/ss/landing/...`](https://plus.google.com/_/apps-static/_/ss/landing/ver=-1jl0uaoze05k5/am=!wzqMmZuXM3CJBf3i2Xr9BkQ/bf=BA/r=O)
and
[`https://plus.google.com/_/apps-static/_/js/landing/...`](https://plus.google.com/_/apps-static/_/js/landing/si_l/rt=j/ver=xhJosewxYGM.en./am=!wzqMmZuXM3CJBf3i2Xr9BkQ/d=1/).

These URLs mainly appear to be CSS, Javascript, and JSON, but there might be other things (that are more valuable to search engines) which aren't immediately obvious.